# Interactive page builder using vue components

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, wysiwyg

I'm using Nuxt.js for building static websites and I want to create a visual page builder based on existing components. So I want to manage file structure (with any depth) and it's content (placing and order predifined components with props and slots) through the UI. Help me to start with it. What is the best approach to use? Thanks!

[image: file structure] [image: file content]

Answer (score 0):

As far as I got your mean, you wanna generate static pages automatically, the best solution of that is a `_slug` file, you can `provide a _slug.vue file inside the root of pages directory` then pas the component name as a slug such as `yourdomain.com/your components name`, you are able to access your slug name by `this.$route.params.slug` then you can provide a route object in slug.vue file to assign your desired component to route based on your slug component name, refer to this document: https://nuxtjs.org/guide/routing/

Comment: I edited my question to make it clearer. If your solution still fits, I'll try it, Thanks!